# Cannot display the validation message outside the form tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble displaying the validation message outside the form tag.

## What I've tried

- Make sure the return value of "${#fields.errors('${office}')}" is always false.
- Make sure field errors happens when a input value is invalid.

## Source Codes

### A Part of Controller

```
 @PostMapping("/for_office/office_modify")
  public String updateOffice(
      Locale locale,
      Model model,
      RedirectAttributes attrs,
      @Valid @ModelAttribute Office office,
      BindingResult bindingResult)
      throws ParseException {
    attrs.addFlashAttribute("templateName", ViewNameConst.OFFICE_VIEW_NAME);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      logger.info("OfficeController:updateOffice:hasErrors");
      logger.info(bindingResult.toString());
      return ViewNameConst.OFFICE_VIEW_NAME;
    }
    ...
  }
```

### A Part Of Thymeleaf Template

```
<ul class="errMsg text-danger"  th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('${office}')}">
  <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('${office}')}" th:text="${err}">
    Input is incorrect
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this problem and I resolved this. I placed the error messages inside the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong syntax in your template.
Try to display this for all errors:

```
<div class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
    <p th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></p>    
</div>
```

I don't know your Office model but you can try this for individual error:

```
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('yourModelInstance.propertyName')}" 
 class="label label-danger" th:errors="*{yourModelInstance.propertyName}">Error here</p>
```

Comment: I'd like to display the error messages for all errors **outside** the form tag(whose th:object attribute value is "office").
I think your first example is not suitable for me(Thymeleaf can't resolve '*' because th:object attribute is not defined)